# CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader: how to specify categories with regex? 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am trying to create a CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader with two categories: neg and pos. Ths categories are in the file name as "_neg" and "_pos". Examples:

```
bda_TD_2520_HD_001.pdf_neg.txt
info_Ei650_de.pdf_pos
```

My code:

```
reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('C:/users/s/desktop/corpus/', r'.*\.txt',
cat_pattern=r'.*(pos|neg)\.txt')
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I changed it, now the original error doesn't occur anymore. I'm not sure that it worked, though, because I don't get any results:

```
len(reader.categories()) # nothing

for cat in reader.categories():
    print (cat) # nothing

reader.fileids("neg") # ValueError: Category neg not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look through the files that contain `pos` or `neg` only:

```
CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('C:/users/s/desktop/corpus/', 
                                 r'.*?_(neg|pos).*', 
                                 cat_pattern=r'.*?_(neg|pos).*')
```

where `.*?` is a *[non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)* match for any characters any number of times, `(neg|pos)` is a capturing group (it has to be capturing for the category extractor to work) that would match either `neg` or `pos`.

Works for me.

Comment: "@user3813234 quick check - how about `.*?_(?:pos|neg)(?:\.txt)?`?

Comment: No, the category is still not found.

Comment: @user3813234 added a working solution to the answer. I'll add some explanation, while you are checking if it works for you. Thanks.